# Is blowing the foods Makruh? (Shia view)

Tags: practical-islam, shiism, food, makruh

It is said that it is better not to blow the foods. In other word, it is said that blowing the foods is considered as a makruh practice. So, I was wondering if this is counted as a correct issue or not? If so, is there any related hadith (tradition) or Fatwa (ruling) concerning that?

*Note: I am looking for the viewpoint of Shia (hadiths or Fatwas)*

Answer (score 1):

Briefly speaking, concerning your question as you inquired for:

> it is said that blowing the foods is considered as a makruh practice.
>   So, I was wondering if this is counted as a correct issue or not? If
>   so, is there any related hadith (tradition) or Fatwa (ruling)
>   concerning that?

Yes. According to Shia Maraja (Marja’al-Taqlids) it is deemed as a Makruh act to blow whatever you eat or drink. (Which can be declared based on the hadiths expressed in the Fatawa cited in reference).

*Note: Makruh means: It is not haram, but it is better not to do it. (due do various reasons ...)*

---

**Reference:**

> [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/2037#gsc.tab=0)